# What can cause Identity Provider initiated SSO to fail

Tags: single-sign-on, saml

We wrote our own Identity Provider on a SharePoint server and the SAML 2.0 looks pretty good. We are posting to a third party Service Provider on the same network. The Post is Base 64 encoded. They have a setting in their web.config that asks if the SAML is encoded or not, and if you say no and it is encoded, their documentation indicates it is supposed to log an error indicating as such. Since there is no error logged, I am assuming something is failing in the cross-site post. We are definitely hitting their SSO Consumer page as they log the URLReferer and it is the correct machine listed that is initiating the SSO...

What might be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the control name setting in the Service Provider web.config was incorrect because of the ASP.NET naming convention for the control bearing the SAMLResponse when set to `runat="server"` In the Identity Provider.